# override setOnClickListener in a fragment stop working

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I m a novice programmer and I have a problem with my app.

Its an activity with 4 fragment with a viewpager.
I have 1 button in each fragment that do something when you click on it.

when I click on the button in fragment 1 and scroll down to fragment 4 and go back to fragment 1.
The button in fragment 1 stop working.

if you dont click the button in fragment 1 and and scroll down to fragment 4 and go back to fragment 1. The button works fine.

The problem appears when I click the button and after scrolling to a distant fragment and return I click again.

Main:

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), OnFragmentActionsListener   {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme)
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val fragmentAdapter = PageAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager)
        viewPager.adapter = fragmentAdapter
        val mPager: ViewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager)
        mPager.setPageTransformer(true, PageAdapter.ZoomOutPageTransformer())
        tablayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)

}
       override fun onClickFragment1btn1() {
        //here i do something when click the button like do a
            }
```

viewpager:

```
class PageAdapter  (val context: Context, fm: FragmentManager): FragmentStatePagerAdapter(fm) {
    override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> {FOne()}
            1 -> {FTwo()}
            2 -> {FThree()}
            else -> {return FFour()}
        }
    }
    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return 4
    }
    override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
        return when (position) {
            0 -> "tab1"
            1 -> "tab2"
            2 -> "tab3"
            else -> {
                return "tab4"
            }
        }
    }
```

Interface:

```
interface OnFragmentActionsListener {
    //Fragment 1:
    fun onClickFragment1btn1()
    //Fragment 2:
    fun onClickFragment1btn2()
    //Fragment 3:
    fun onClickFragment1btn3()
    //Fragment 4:
    fun onClickFragment1btn4()
}
```

Fragment:

```
class FOne : Fragment() {
    private var listener: OnFragmentActionsListener? = null
    val TAG = "FragmentOne"
    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        Log.d(TAG, "onAtach")
        if (context is OnFragmentActionsListener) {
            listener = context
        } else {
            throw   RuntimeException(context!!.toString() +"must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener")
        }
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate")
    }
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View?{
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_f_one, container, false)
    }
    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        btn1.setOnClickListener{listener?.onClickFragment1btn1() }
    }
  
    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        listener = null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best approach for this are :

**Approach 1:**

Set this line on your viewpager :

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```

This will keep 4 fragment in your memory.

Answer (score 0):

Ankit thanks you.

For people looking at this bug.
The problem is in the savedInstance.
The button works fine, but the 2 edittext with information don't take new values after onDestroy.
The operation with the button works with the saved instance (the values that i put in first operation before change page)

For my App setOffscreenPageLimit is perfect because it have only 4 fragment.
If you have much more pages It may cause memory shortage.

Android developer answer:
""
open fun setOffscreenPageLimit(limit: Int): Unit
Set the number of pages that should be retained to either side of the current page in the view hierarchy in an idle state. Pages beyond this limit will be recreated from the adapter when needed.

This is offered as an optimization. If you know in advance the number of pages you will need to support or have lazy-loading mechanisms in place on your pages, tweaking this setting can have benefits in perceived smoothness of paging animations and interaction. If you have a small number of pages (3-4) that you can keep active all at once, less time will be spent in layout for newly created view subtrees as the user pages back and forth.
""

fix for kotlin in my app:

```
 //PageAdapter Starts
        val fragmentAdapter = PageAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager)
        viewPager.adapter = fragmentAdapter
        val mPager: ViewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager)
        mPager.offscreenPageLimit = 4 <--- solution
        mPager.setPageTransformer(true, PageAdapter.ZoomOutPageTransformer())
        tablayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager)
        //Page Adapter ends
```